# Lightweight variable visible to all scripts in same gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

My player's character has several scripts attached.

Now I would like to add one variable that should be accessible by a few other scripts in this gameobject.

I need to show the gameobject in an inventory scene. I move him into the inventory scene by

```
SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(Hero, InventoryScene);
```

While the gameobject is shown in this inventory scene, the player shouldn't be able to move it.

So I would like to add a variable named "isFrozen" to the gameobject. When this variable is true, no player input will be processed.

The movement logic goes over 3 scripts.

How could I best make it known (in a lightweight fasion) to the scripts that the player is currently frozen?

Or should I try to combine them into 1 script and add this variable to this single script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have single variable accessed by multiple classes. Remember static variables are always here for this reason. You can either access this 'isFrozen' variable by making the variable as **static** or make the class in which the variable present as **[singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Singleton)** and access that variable. Just make sure it is a public variable and all good to go.
If you make 'isFrozen' static then you can directly access it as `MyClass.isFrozen`.
If you make a singleton class than you can access it like `MyClass.Instance.isFrozen`;

Comment: Note that `static` and `singleton` have completely different implications. Yes, they can both be "accessed from anywhere" but that's not why they're used.

Comment: @Draco18s yes indeed. It depends on the context of the usage. Singleton will give access to instance variables while static can be accessed by directly.